# How to format a shared partition which you can access even if you have hybernated

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hibernate, shared-folders

I have searched for this specific question but I didn't find anything useful. I have created a shared partition so that I can access it both from Windows and Xubuntu; it is an NTFS partition. The problem is that since I mounted it in Windows and I hibernate Windows, I can only access the shared partition in read-only mode. I would like to be able to read/write to the shared partition even if I hibernated Windows. I am therefore wondering how do I do that. Which partition type should I use? I would like the shared partition to be kind of like a removable drive; even if I hibernate Windows I can still read/write to the removable drive from linux.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do not know if this also applies to Windows 10 or not: http://superuser.com/questions/295913/how-to-mount-and-unmount-hard-drives-under-windows-the-unix-way

Comment: I checked it out but I cant try it our right now, will reply in the morning.

Comment: You can't mount the same filesystem at the same time from two different operating systems.

Comment: That seems to somewhat work. If I manually unmount the shared partition using mountvol Z: /p in cmd, I can access the shared partition in linux. But if I set up a .bat script to do that same command when windows goes to sleep (hibernates) I can't access the shared partition on linux. Does anyone know how would I unmount the partition before windows goes to sleep(hibernates)?